# Slow Downloads from Nextcloud terminate after 60secs

Tags: php, docker, apache, nextcloud

I have a Nextcloud instance running in a Docker Container. All fine so far, apart from the downloads by users with a slow internet connection. The downloads terminate after 60secs. Fast downloads succeed.

I can reproduce the problem on the local network with a file manager, which I can throttle down to slow download rates. So it is not a problem with the reverse proxy I am using for public traffic, it seems to be a local issue. No reverse proxy or anything else involved. Straight forward, Nextcloud and me. ;-)

When I run a DL at a speed of 256kB/s it gets to 16mB before it stops after 60secs. With 128kB/s it gets to 8mB before it stops, again, after 60sec. It seems to be a timing issue, not a quantity issue. A download with 512 kB/s, on the other hand, successfully downloads the entire file of 700mB+.

After loads of searching on the web and trying various changes, it still won't work.

```
- Docker'ed Nextcloud 21.0.1 (latest), containing:
    + PHP 7.4.18
    + apache2 2.4.38
```

What I've done so far is:

In `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`:

```
TimeOut 600
```

In `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini`:

```
default_socket_timeout = 600
max_execution_time = 600
```

All of the changes I successfully verified in `phpinfo();`, so the changes are effective. All other settings are the standard settings Nextcloud is shipped with.

Status is, the downloads still terminate after exactly 60sec.

Nextcloud's logs are of no help. No mention of a termination or the reason for it.

Are there any other timeout settings I didn't come across?

Regards

Carsten

Comment: Maybe you have some other protection mechanism in place like "suhosin"?

Comment: Also test out other php settings, for example `max_input_time` and `default_socket_timeout` ...

Comment: @arkascha, thanks for the hints. Unfortunately, no success. I've added this to my post. Other tools are not installed, nor involved. The container has been installed and is being accessed via the IP, which is mapped into the container.

`max_input_time` is `-1`, so that one is out of the game.

Comment: Just to make sure the obvious is not forgotten: you did change the php settings of the php variant used by nextcloud? None of the other variants? 'Cause they are independent?

Comment: `request_terminate_timeout` also comes into my mind, but I assume you went through all php settings, right?

Comment: What about the settings of the apache http server? It has it's own timeout control, especially relevant for fastcgi situation (which I assume you are using) ... What does the error log of the apache http server say?